# Bakcup Base de datos Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Buenas tardes, tengo una aplicación en Django 1.10 en la cual hoy me es necesario crear una copia de seguridad de la bd, esta copia se debe hacer cuando el usuario de click en un boton que se ubicara en un template y descargar la copia en el equipo del usuario.

En mis views.py tengo lo siguiente.

```
def backup(request):
    subprocess.Popen("mysqldump -u root -p12345 victimas > /home/proyecto/backup.sql")
    subprocess.Popen("gzip -c /home/proyecto/backup.sql > /home/proyecto/backup.gz")
    dataf = open('/home/proyecto/backups/backup.gz', 'r')
    return HttpResponse(dataf.read(), mimetype='application/x-gzip')
```

Pero me genera el error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: django mysqldump
```

Al hacerlo directamente desde la consolo me crea el archivo, ya verifique los permisos de la carpeta.

Agradezco su colaboración

Comment: Mmmm...espero que la seguridad de tu aplicacion sea optima, de modo que no permita a cualquier persona el obtener el script de la base de datos junto a su informacion...podrias dar un poco mas de detalles sobre el porque de esta decision...tal vez con descargar un csv baste y sobre....

Comment: Realmente lo que necesito es que el usuario obtenga una copia de la base de datos, de modo que se pueda restaurar en caso de ser necesario, la seguridad no es problema ya que es para una aplicación local.

Comment: Porque mejor no programas un respaldo de la base de datos por medio de un cron job?

Comment: Asi era como lo tenia planteado pero el requerimiento es que el usuario lo genere y descargue el archivo ya que este tendra la informacion contenida hasta ese momento

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer, es ejecutar `pg_dump` desde python para generar al archive en disco(de preferencia en una carpeta de tu aplicacion), luego generar el link de descarga en base al nombre del respaldo, la carpeta donde se guardo y la url de tu aplicacion(con un simple a href debiese bastar)...sigue este articulo sobre el primer item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380273/pg-dump-pg-restore-password-using-python-module-subprocess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en como se ejecuta el Popen, prueba del siguiente modo:

```
subprocess.Popen("mysqldump -u root -p12345 victimas > /home/proyecto/backup.sql", shell=True)
```

Aquí viene info sobre ello, [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)